# Does OpenSSL have GMAC API and examples

Tags: authentication, openssl, aes-gcm

I am working on a project which needs to do authentication on large volume of data. It seems GMAC is designed for high throughput operation. I only need the message authentication code, encryption is not required.
Does OpenSSL has GMAC API or examples that only computes the GMAC code?

I know GCM is for encryption and authentication, but for my case encryption is not needed. Are there any examples for only GMAC computation using openssl?

Answer (score 5):

> Does OpenSSL have GMAC API and examples...

The OpenSSL wiki has a Authenticated Encryption mode example at [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption).

GMAC is a special case of GCM mode. From NIST's [Special Publication 800-38D](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38D/SP-800-38D.pdf):

> If the GCM input is restricted to data that is not to be encrypted,
>   the resulting specialization of GCM, called GMAC, is simply an
>   authentication mode on the input data...

So all you need to do is send data into the Additional Authenticated Data (AAD) channel, and not the Plain text (PT) channel.

Here's an example that uses a test vector from NIST's [GCM Test Vectors](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/). Notice the PT data is empty, and only AAD data is provided:

```
 [Keylen = 128]
 [IVlen = 96]
 [PTlen = 0]
 [AADlen = 128]
 [Taglen = 128]

 Count = 0
 Key = 77be63708971c4e240d1cb79e8d77feb
 IV = e0e00f19fed7ba0136a797f3
 PT =
 AAD = 7a43ec1d9c0a5a78a0b16533a6213cab
 CT =
 Tag = 209fcc8d3675ed938e9c7166709dd946
```

And here's the program that uses the hard-coded data (and on Pastebin at [OpenSSL GMAC example](http://pastebin.com/v3J93Cj4)):

```
int rc = 0, unused;
unsigned int i;

byte key[] = { 0x77, 0xbe, 0x63, 0x70, 0x89, 0x71, 0xc4, 0xe2,
               0x40, 0xd1, 0xcb, 0x79, 0xe8, 0xd7, 0x7f, 0xeb };
byte iv[] = { 0xe0, 0xe0, 0x0f, 0x19, 0xfe, 0xd7, 0xba, 0x01,
              0x36, 0xa7, 0x97, 0xf3 };
byte aad[] = { 0x7a, 0x43, 0xec, 0x1d, 0x9c, 0x0a, 0x5a, 0x78,
               0xa0, 0xb1, 0x65, 0x33, 0xa6, 0x21, 0x3c, 0xab };

byte tag[16] = { /* calculated */ };
byte exp[] = { 0x20, 0x9f, 0xcc, 0x8d, 0x36, 0x75, 0xed, 0x93,
               0x8e, 0x9c, 0x71, 0x66, 0x70, 0x9d, 0xd9, 0x46 };

EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = NULL;

ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
ASSERT(ctx != NULL);

rc = EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_gcm(), NULL, NULL, NULL);
ASSERT(rc == 1);

rc = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, sizeof(iv), NULL);
ASSERT(rc == 1);

rc = EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv);
ASSERT(rc == 1);

rc = EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, NULL, &unused, aad, sizeof(aad));
ASSERT(rc == 1);

rc = EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, NULL, &unused);
ASSERT(rc == 1);

rc = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_GET_TAG, sizeof(tag), tag);
ASSERT(rc == 1);

printf("Calculated tag:\n  ");
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(tag); i++)
{
    printf("%02x", tag[i]);

    if(i == sizeof(tag) - 1) {
        printf("\n");
    }
}

printf("Expected tag:\n  ");
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(exp); i++)
{
    printf("%02x", exp[i]);

    if(i == sizeof(exp) - 1) {
        printf("\n");
    }
}

if(ctx) {
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
}
```

And finally, here's the output of the program:

```
$ ./t.exe
Calculated tag:
  209fcc8d3675ed938e9c7166709dd946
Expected tag:
  209fcc8d3675ed938e9c7166709dd946
```

Comment: The only thing I would add to this excellent answer is a link to the openssl manual page which covers GCM: https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_EncryptInit.html

Comment: thank you very much @jww! I have another issue... If the AADlen, Keylen and Taglen are not equal, how to produce the expected tag in the NIST test file using openssl? For example `[Keylen = 128]
[IVlen = 96]
[PTlen = 0]
[AADlen = 160]
[Taglen = 64]

Count = 0
Key = 3f8777b7c6a4d0962da25da68363f84d
IV = 73f30f2b5aa317f9fcff5482
PT = 
AAD = e12756b90bac548fb300756668dbd0e395ecd5ca
CT = 
Tag = cb8e9900c2dfe6a6` I cannot get this Tag cb8e9900c2dfe6a6...